# Redirect standard output of another process

Tags: redirect, input, output, standards

I would like to get the standard output and input of an existing process.
The only option I found was to start the process for example in C# with the Process-Type and redirect standard input and output in the StartInfo. However, I cannot redirect standard input and output of a running process.

Background: There is a GUI-process I have no access to that starts a process and redirects stdout and -in to an own function. I would like to spy the communication between the GUI-process and the console-process.

Is there a way to access standard input and output of another process? Probably in C++?